# Toyota Gaia 2001 model. ABS check light showing. Speedometer not working

Tags: sensor, air

My car is showing ABS check light, the speedometer is not working. The fuel consumption is high, and it's slow in changing from first gear.

I don't know if any of these faults are connected. What should I do?

Comment: What are the abs codes? Sounds like a bad WSS for the abs light and speedo.